# route post wont work angularjs / MEAN

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

Im trying to post a action number from client sided to server sided, and recieve a response from the server, but i do get:

```
angular.js:8467 POST SITE:3000/posts/test 404 (Not Found)
```

what is wrong with my code?

server sided index.js

```
    router.post('/posts/test', auth, function(req, res, next) {


res.json("success");

});
```

angularjs client file ( under post service):

```
o.crimePerform = function(post) {
      return $http.post('/posts/test', post, {
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
  }).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log("performed crime!");
  });
}
```

angularjs client file ( acual action performed)

```
    $scope.performacrime  = function(action) {
    console.log("performing action number " + action.id);
    posts.crimePerform({crimeaction : action.id});
    $scope.status = action.name + ' loading...';


    $scope.crimeresult = true;


}
```

response: `angular.js:8467 POST WEBSITE:3000/posts/test 404 (Not Found)`

**EDIT:** the response from server is just an example. No matter what the response is, it wont work.

Comment: can you just fiddle it out?

Comment: @KunalKakkad seriously ? how can he fiddle this out ?

Comment: @KunalKakkad dont know how to do that.

Comment: you can publish your rest service and reference it to angular code.
And provide a button and on click you can call your post function from angular.

Comment: @maria what is this ? [test:22]

Comment: you want to return posts in the request response right ?

Comment: can't you just res.json(post);

Comment: @ZeRubeus just some test response.

Comment: For clarity of this example, I'd change res.json([test:22]); to something like res.json("success"); only because with what you've provided, test would be undefined, potentially throwing an error and causing your response to never come back.

Comment: @wake changing to it now

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't appear to be with your angular POST. It's on the server side.  Your server side code is erroring out.

I tried for example:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"Authorization":"Bearer xyz"}' http://178.62.5.64:3000/posts/test

Which came back with:

```
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<h2>404</h2>
<pre>Error: Not Found
    at /opt/mean/app.js:48:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/rout
er/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:13)
    at /opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:237:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (/opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/router/
index.js:312:12)
    at /opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:228:12
    at Function.match_layer (/opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:
295:3)
    at next (/opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:10)
    at /opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:191:16
    at Function.match_layer (/opt/mean/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:
295:3)</pre>
```

Your server side route is being invoked, and it looks like the error handling is giving the 404 response.

Comment: what should i do?, could we chat @wake ?

Comment: dosent it exist a chat feature here on stackoverflow?